# Getting duplicate email on schedule report in maximo

Tags: birt, maximo

Getting duplicate email on schedule report in maximo.

Only couple of reports which is getting duplicate emails at the same time to inbox on schedule reports.

Eclipse Version: 3.7.1
Build id: M20110909-1335

Maximo SmartCloud Control Desk 7.5.1.0.

Any one face the same issue.

Thanks & Regards
Roshan

Answer (score 0):

Go to the module which contains your scheduled BIRT report. My example will be Work Order Tracking.

- From that module, Select Action > Run Reports

[image: Run Reports]

- Navigate to the schedule report
- Highlight the report
- Click on Scheduling Status tab

[image: Highlight Scheduled Report]

- If there are multiple rows, then delete one so that you receive only one scheduled report.

[image: Delete duplicate scheduled report]

Comment: Can you clarify what you just wrote?